# Enable disabled buttons on click of div using HTML, CSS, Jquery?

Tags: css, html, button, onclick

I'd appreciate any help for the disabled/enabled button issue I'm having. I'm learning Jquery so solving this problem will be a big lesson for me. I've made a list of users using div classes:

```
<div class="userList">
    <div class="user">Tom</div>
    <div class="user">Ben</div>
    <div class="user">George</div>
    <div class="user">Tony</div>
</div>
```

Under the list of users I have four buttons:

```
<div class="actions">
    <button id="add" disabled="disabled">Add</button>
    <button id="block" disabled="disabled">Block</button>
    <button id="message" disabled="disabled">Message</button>
    <button id="exit">Exit</button>
</div>
```

As you can see, 3 of 4 buttons are disabled by default. What I want to do is click on a user which will highlight the user with a background colour and at the same time will enable the 3 disabled buttons. I also would like to target the individual buttons by ID. Only the username I click on should change background colour and change back to original colour once I click on another username or outside the 'userList' div.

This is the full HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <div class="userList">
        <div class="user">Tom</div>
        <div class="user">Ben</div>
        <div class="user">George</div>
        <div class="user">Tony</div>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
        <button id="add" disabled="disabled">Add</button>
        <button id="block" disabled="disabled">Block</button>
        <button id="message" disabled="disabled">Message</button>
        <button id="exit">Exit</button>
    </div>

</div>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

#wrapper {
    width:300px;
    min-height:100px;
    background-color:#ddd;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:20px;
    }

.userList {
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    padding:20px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    }

.user {
    background:#eee;
    line-height:28px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:10px;
    }
    .user:hover {
        background:#06F;
        color:#fff;
        border:1px solid #000;
        }

.actions {}
```

I hope somebody can help me with this! This will teach me and hopefully many more people a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood your problem correctly, then maybe something like this would do:

```
$('.user').click(function(event){
    removeHighlight();
    $(event.target).addClass('highlight'); // Highlight selected item
    $('.btn-action').attr('disabled', false); // Enable action buttons
});

$(document).click(function(event) {
    // If clicked element does not have the class 'userList'
    // and does not have a parent element with a class 'userList'
    if(!$(event.target).hasClass('userList') && !$(event.target).parents('.userList').length) {
        removeHighlight();
        $('.btn-action').attr('disabled', true); // Disable action buttons
    }
});

function removeHighlight() {
    $('.user').each(function() { // Remove highlight class for any previously selected item
        $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    });
}
```

Add this to your styles:

```
.user.highlight {
    background:#06F;
    color:#fff;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

And add `btn-action` class to your buttons.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help. I've input all the code and changes you suggested but for some reason it's not working. I've linked the js in an external sheet and I've also included the jquery library in the head section. The only change I've seen it once I click outside the 'userList' div, the exit button disables because I added the .btn-action class to exit button for testing purposes. The divs are not highlighting and the buttons are not enabling.

Comment: Are there any console errors? What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I've linked to this: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> . There are no console errors.

Comment: If there are console errors, kindly post them here. Also try comparing your code with the fiddle I linked above and see if there are any differences.

Comment: Thanks so much for your time. This must be a newb error because I've copied your code exactly and it's still not working. I must be doing something wrong with my .js file.

Comment: Anyway, I'll play around with this until it works. Your fiddle works 100% how I want it to. Thank so much for your help!

Comment: Can you try including `https://` in your script that links to the jQuery library? So basically: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: It already is like that. I've also copy/pasted your link. Still same thing.

Comment: Hi, I've just got it to work. All I did was place the external js file just before the closing body tag. Thank you so much!!! It's exactly what I was after.

Comment: Ah, yes. I was actually about to mention that next in case adding `https://` did not work (misread the link). Important lesson to learn too, ideally your scripts should be placed before the closing body tag to ensure that all the elements have been rendered before any references to them in your scripts are processed. Good job. Glad I was able to help. :)